# How to build a list of numpy arrays where each array is uniquely sized

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a python list of numpy arrays, where each array in the list will have unique dimensions - how I can construct it and also alter a specific entry within a specific within the list on the fly?

For example: I have three matrices (numpy arrays) with dimensions MxN, PxQ and AxB where {A,B,P,Q,M,N} are all unique integers. I'd like to have all three numpy arrays in the same list, and be able to extract or alter specific entries in each matrix within the list.

Is this possible with python/numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible. Actually, if you're putting them into a Python `list` (not a `numpy` list) it's possible with *any* three objects.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((1, 2))
B = np.zeros((3, 4))
C = np.zeros((5, 6))
the_list = [A, B, C]
```

You can access these objects via `the_list[0]`, `the_list[1]` and `the_list[2]` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the list:

```
l = [np.zeros((M, N)), np.zeros((P,Q)), np.zeros((A,B))]
```

And use `0`, `1` or `2` to get to the element you want.